# Labeling data points

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to label data points using *a power of 3* format, i.e. `24^3`.
For instance,

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5]
B = [100,200,300,400,500]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.plot(A,B)
n=[24,48,96,192]
for i, txt in enumerate(n):
   ax.annotate(txt, (A[i],B[i]))
plt.show()
```

[image]

So,instead of `n=[24,48,96,192]`, I would like to see `24^3,48^3,96^3`... or even better if I could use an improved representation for the power of 3.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need only a small change in your annotate call:

```
for i, txt in enumerate(n):
    ax.annotate(str(txt) + '$^3$', (A[i],B[i]))
```

With '$ ...$' you can enter some kind of mathematical mode. 
See more details here: http://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html

The result should look like:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

See: http://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

A = [1,2,3,4,5]
B = [100,200,300,400,500]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.plot(A,B)
n=[24,48,96,192]
for i, txt in enumerate(n):
   ax.annotate(r'${}^3$'.format(txt), (A[i],B[i]))
plt.show()
```

[image]